# How do I upgrade my TensoFlow 1.0.0 to 2.2.0 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm really a beginner so please be nice to me.
I wanted to upload my machine learning model from Google Colab, into Visual Studio Code (that has Flask).

My model needs Keras and Tensorflow, so I installed those into my VSC. 
However Keras only works with Tensorflow 2.2.0, and my Tensorflow is 1.0.0
When I want to upgrade it with `pip install tensorflow==2.2.0`, it gives me

```
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0rc1
```

I don't know whats the difference between Anaconda, Python and Visual Studio Code. So I tried upgrading TensorFlow in Anaconda.. it worked. But not in my VSC. 
My Python interpreter is 3.8.5 64-bit (conda)

Comment: Check the interpreter configured with VS code. Select the correct interpreter and install

Comment: I found out that the interpreter displayed at bottom right is different that the interpreter in terminal. At bottom right, I've changed my interpreter to Python 3.5 .. but when I run python --version, the terminal showed me that I got Python 3.9.

Comment: Well, you can click on the python version shown in the bottom, and select the interpreter path. After that, close the existing terminal and open it again.

Comment: I've fixed the problem. What I did was delete Python 3.9 and change it to Python 3.5 in virtual environment. I made sure I restarted my computer as well as VScode.

Comment: Tensorflow support for Python 3.9 is still under progress.Take look at [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44485) for more info. Use Python <3.9 until it support. Thanks!